# Action methods in ServiceApiController is not catching the request

Tags: sitecore-api

I'm using Sitecore 9 and I have created a ServiceApiController to enhance Sitecore API.

I put a simple action method but it doesn't catch any request and I get this exception:

> Document not found - 404

Here is my controller:

```
using Sitecore.Services.Core;
using Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SPCW.Feature.SalesforceBridge.Controllers
{
    public class TestApi : ServicesApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        [System.Web.Http.Route("v1/test")]
        public IHttpActionResult testMethod()
        {
            return Ok<string>("Test was successful");
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <api>
      <services>
        <configuration type="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Configuration.ServicesConfiguration, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure">
          <allowedControllers hint="list:AddController">
            <allowedController desc="TestApi">SPCW.Feature.SalesforceBridge.Controllers.TestApi, SPCW.Feature.SalesforceBridge</allowedController>
          </allowedControllers>
        </configuration>
      </services>
    </api>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to add "Controller" at the end of your controller class name so instead of `TestApi` it will be `TestApiController` to follow MVC naming conventions.

Second, I think that better would be to decorate your class with this attribute `[ServicesController("v1.test")]` .

Then the call would look like this:
`http://localhost/sitecore/api/ssc/v1/test/1/TestMethod`